# Camera.release() blocked after taking a photo

Tags: android, android-camera

After taking a picture I use the function release() to end the image capture operation.

On some devices this function blocks the UI thread for 1-12 seconds.

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data,
                    Camera camera) {

                    //Img process code (...)

                    Log.e("release","Start");//O second
                    mCamera.release();
                    Log.e("release","End"); //+ 12 second        


            }

}
```

For example in galaxy tab 4 with the front camera is blocked for 1 second and the back camera for 12 seconds.

Any idea?

Comment: Why is `onPictureTaken()` `synchronized`?

Comment: It's been an error copying the code. Actually is not synchronized

Comment: What happens if you release the camera in `onPause()`?

Comment: You may need to use the camera again before the onPause method is called.

Comment: That is fine. I am saying it to release it inside `onPause()`. The camera should be released when you do not need it anymore. Not after every time a picture is taken.

Comment: I need to call the method release() immediately after taking the picture because then I need to use the camera again by another app and must be released. I need a solution to explain to me why the release() method takes so long to run and how decrease this time.

Comment: As soon as your `Activity` goes on the background to switch to the other app, `onPause()` will be called, hence the camera will be released...

Comment: I'm not worth that solution, in so few lines can not explain why not okay. It is a very very complex application. I need a solution to explain to me why the release() method takes so long. I will accept a solution that tells me that it's normal method relase () takes so long in some devices.